# PHP/JSON Returning Value of 1

Tags: php, json, api

I'm working on a tool to query a government database or information. Sam.gov actually. They have a public API and up until now everything has been going smooth but I ran into an issue with an array that returns a 1 instead of the word "Yes" That I'd like it to.

http://gsa.github.io/sam_api/sam/fields.html  (This is the API documentation)

Here is the code that I can't figure out...

```
foreach($decoded_results['sam_data']['registration']['naics'] as $naics){
    echo '<strong>Is Primary: </strong>'.$naics['isPrimary'].'</br>';
    echo '<strong>Naics Code: </strong>'.$naics['naicsCode'].'</br>';
    echo '<strong>Naics Name: </strong>'.$naics['naicsName'].'</br>';
}
```

I need the isprimary to return a Yes or a No instead of nothing of a number 1, anyone have any solutions?

Comment: `'.$naics['isPrimary'].'` to `'. ($naics['isPrimary'] == true)?'yes':'no' .'`

Comment: In many programming language 1 == true and 0 == false

Comment: `echo '<strong>Is Primary: </strong>' . ($naics['isPrimary'] ? 'yes' : 'no') .'</br>';`

Answer (score 1):

From the api link `isPrimary` is `boolean` type so

your code should be

```
foreach($decoded_results['sam_data']['registration']['naics'] as $naics)
{
    echo '<strong>Is Primary: </strong>'.($naics['isPrimary'] === true)?'yes':'no'.'</br>';
    echo '<strong>Naics Code: </strong>'.$naics['naicsCode'].'</br>';
    echo '<strong>Naics Name: </strong>'.$naics['naicsName'].'</br>';
}
```

Comment: Tried what you suggest and now every line returns a value of yes although I know only one of them should say yes. You can check out what's happening for yourself by going to samhelpdesk.us and using the search tool on the home page. In the search box enter 609108654 and select DUNS Number as the criteria. Click Search and when the results return scroll down and click see more information, on that page scroll down the NAICS section and you'll see. It just repeats yes a bunch of times. I know it's returning an array but I'm at a total loss how to parse it.

Comment: Still getting a return of yes for everything displayed in the array.

Comment: @JohnChase can you do `var_dump($naics['isPrimary']);` in foreach for testing..... let me know the output... :)